# Выбрать из базы варианты, содержащие часть переменной

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Привет всем кодерам. 
Вопрос такой.

Допустим у меня есть переменная $phone = 725968937885545

И в базе есть столбец phone с номером 8937885545

Как построить sql запрос, чтобы найти совпадения?

```
 Select * from  info  WHERE `phone` LIKE '...%
```

Может оператор какой-то есть? 
Т.е. мне надо найти совпадения 10 одинаковых чисел идущих подряд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так?

```
$query = "SELECT *
                FROM info
                WHERE ". $phone. " LIKE concat('%',phone,'%')";
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT *
            FROM info
            WHERE phone LIKE "%' . $phone . '%"';
```

где `%` - любое количество символов.

Совет: не ипользуйте выбор всех полей при помощи `*`. Перечисляйте необходимые поля через запятую.

Comment: Получится 
$query = 'SELECT *
            FROM info
            WHERE phone LIKE "%725968937885545%"';

Понятное дело, что запрос будет нулевым. Потому что в базе номер короче.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не внимательно прочитал вопрос. В таком случае, думаю, что без регулярных выражений вам не обойтись. Я в них не силен, может кто-то составит вам.